# Date in UserControl

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have been having some confusion here

```
$(function () {
            $("input[id*=ucFromDate], input[id*=ucToDate]").click(function () {

                var fromDate = $("input[id*=ucFromDate]").val();
                var toDate = $("input[id*=ucToDate]").val();

                if ($("input[id*=ucFromDate]").val().length != 0 && $("input[id*=ucToDate]").val().length != 0)
                {
                    var dateFrom = dateUTC(fromDate);
                    var dateTo = dateUTC(toDate);

                    alert(dateTo.toString());
                    alert(dateFrom.toString());


                }

            });
        });

        function dateUTC(date) {
            var date = date.split("-");
            return new Date(date[2], date[0]-1, date[1]);
        }
```

I am getting value like this
**2013-04-1**
on second click I see **[[2013,4,1]]**, in addition sometime I see the value in the textbox sometime I don't even when there is a value and the value are from **UserControl**

Comment: If the date really is UTC, you should be using `new Date(Date.UTC(date[2], date[0]-1, date[1]))` otherwise the new date will be out by the local timezone offset (unless the timezone is GMT).

Comment: @RobG Yeah I did that too but the result is same, why I am getting different value like [[2013,4,1]] prior to conversion when I alert fromDate?? second time, during first clik or alert i get a normal 2013-04-1

Comment: No idea. I presume the input value is US mm-dd-yyyy format, in which case the *dateUTC* function should return a suitable date object.

Comment: Does it got to do something with the way I assigned same function to multiple boxes?? when I click the same box its ok but when I click the other box it gives me [[2013,4,1]]